# Add Class When Certain Number Reached

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to add a class and change the color of the text when a certain number is reached in a character count.
Please help me figure out why the class is not being added and the color isn't changing.

```
   <body>
    <form>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="description">Description:</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="description"></textarea>
            <span id="char">0</span> characters
        </div>
    </form>
   </body>

<script>
$('#description').keyup(function(){
    var maxLength = 155;
    var length = $(this).val().length;
    $('#char').text(length);
    if(length > maxLength) {
         $('char').addClass("warning")
    }
});
</script>
```

and in CSS, warning would be color: red

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slightly more elegant way of doing this would be to use `toggleClass` with `state`, that way you don't need the extra if statement.

```js
$('#description').keyup(function(){
    var maxLength = 155;
    var length = $(this).val().length;
    $('#char')
      .text(length)
      .toggleClass("warning", length > maxLength);
});
```

```css
.warning {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="description">Description:</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="description"></textarea>
        <span id="char">0</span> characters
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is just a minor mistake. Update your javascript code as below.

```
$('#description').keyup(function(){
  var maxLength = 155;
  var length = $(this).val().length;
  $('#char').text(length);
  if(length > maxLength) {
      $('#char').addClass("warning");
  } else {
      $('#char').removeClass("warning");
  }
});
```

It will add the "warning" class, so you can add CSS properties in that class to change the color.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to add `#` in the selector.

```js
$('#description').keyup(function() {
  var maxLength = 10;
  var length = $(this).val().length;
  $('#char').text(length);
  if (length > maxLength) {
    $('#char').addClass("warning")
  }
});
```

```css
.warning {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="description">Description:</label>
  <textarea class="form-control" id="description"></textarea>
  <span id="char">0</span> characters
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the color like this also

```
<script>
$('#description').keyup(function(){
  var maxLength = 155;
  var length = $(this).val().length;
  $('#char').text(length);
  if(length > maxLength) {
      $('#char').css("color", "red");
  } else {
      $('#char').css("color", "black");
  }
});
</script>
```